# How do I Calculate capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

There was another question about calculating capacitance between arbitrary shaped conductors where the accepted answer was effectively:

> "Create a grid, place the shapes on the grid giving each point on a conductor its potential, then solve Laplace (by relaxation) for the potential at every point."

It then went on so say

> "Compute the electric field at every point by grad(V) and sum up the implied charge."

OK  I have solved Laplace for my problem on a 513 x 513 point grid and have potentials at every point.  Now what is grad(V)? Well I can use a first or second order finite difference approximator and get a vector Ex,Ey at every point.
But that's a vector and charge is a scalar, so what does it mean "sum up the implied charge"
I think we have to integrate something around a closed boundary encircling one of the conductors, but I am not sure what, given that I need a scalar answer. I can't use div(D)  because Laplace made that zero at every point!

Comment: Link to other question?

Comment: Qmechanic's comment is similar to my comment here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50520/7982